# Why stringbuilder stops adding elements after using the null character?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, null, character

When i am using the null character `'\u0000'`, stringbuilder will stop appending new elements.

For example:

```
StringBuilder _stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
_stringBuilder.append('\u0000');
_stringBuilder.append('a');
System.out.println("."+_stringBuilder+".");
```

returns

```
.
```

I understand that the null value should not be printed (or printed like if it was a null String value) but in this case, why does stringbuilder is failing to add more elements ?

Note: I am using jdk 1.6.0_38 on ubuntu.

Comment: '\0' - null terminator, used as end of string in C and C++ strings

Comment: I doubt that `StringBuilder` has stopped appending new elements. This is more likely an issue in displaying the resulting `String`. What is the `length()` of the `StringBuilder` after appending a few elements?

Comment: I ran your exact code in eclipse on jdk 1.6.0_25 on Win 7 and it prints `. a.`... could be a shell-specific thing.

Comment: I think this is OS specific as Java Strings CAN contain null characters. Win7 over here prints the same

Comment: prints `.a.` here http://ideone.com/BjRKT0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The null character is a reserved character that indicates the end of the string, so if you print something followed by `\u0000`, nothing else after it will be printed.

---

*Why stringbuilder stops adding elements after using the the null character?* It's not really java, it is your terminal that treats `\u0000` as the end of the string.

As someone says, with Windows the output can be `.a.` (i did not test it), this is because windows terminal works differently than Unix-based systems terminal. I'm pretty sure that if you run this code on a OSX machine you will get the same output as the one you get on linux

Comment: It prints a `.`, a box (for the null character), an `a` and a `.` on by windows machine.

Comment: @BheshGurung I think this is because UNIX systems work differently than windows, theoretically if you try the same thing on OSX, it should print `.`

Comment: The null character is not used to terminate Strings in Java.

Comment: null is a reserved character where? Neither gnome-terminal, xterm, nor rxvt have the behaviour described in the question. They all just ignore the null character.

Comment: @Rotsor `\u0000` is used as a standard way to end a string in C-like languages, and terminals used to use it as "end of string" too. You should note that this question is almost 4 years old. Linux is continuously evolving, so things may have changed in these four years. At the time the question was posted the issue was real, but maybe it has been solved meanwhile. And also maybe that some terminal still has this issue on linux. The fact that your terminal version can't reproduce the issue doesn't mean that this question and its answers are wrong (unless you tried **every** terminal/version).

Comment: That's why I'm asking and not saying something is wrong. If you know a terminal that does this, I'm curious. In any case, saying it's a "reserved" character without specifying what piece of software makes it reserved is not a very good answer.

Answer (score 7):

Your `stringBuilder` still appends the elements, see:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append('\u0000');
System.out.println(stringBuilder.length()); // prints 1
stringBuilder.append('a');
System.out.println(stringBuilder.length()); // prints 2
```

My guess is that your console stops printing after the `\u0000` termination character. A different console might handle that differently.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your test, and it does not fail in Eclipse on my Windows 7 system. However, running this test program will distinguish between non-appending and non-printing. I suggest running it in the failing environment.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    StringBuilder _stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    _stringBuilder.append('\u0000');
    _stringBuilder.append('a');
    System.out.println("."+_stringBuilder+".");
    System.out.println(_stringBuilder.length());
    System.out.println(_stringBuilder.charAt(1));
  } 
}
```

If the problem is non-appending, the length will be less than 2, and the attempt to print the character at index 1 will fail. If the problem is non-printing, the length will be 2 and the character at index 1 will be 'a'.

I think that non-printing is much more likely than non-appending.