# StringBuilder setLength()

Tags: java, stringbuilder

```
class Test {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("123");  

        System.out.println(sb + "_");   //123_  // expected ouput

        sb.setLength(2);  
        System.out.println(sb + "_");   //12_   // expected output  

        sb.setLength(3);      
        System.out.println(sb + "_");   //12    // no underscore ????  
    }  
}
```

I don't get why the last output of this Java code does not contain the undercore character. Can anyone explain? Thank you for help.

Comment: Did you read what setLength does? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setLength%28int%29

Comment: Because the `setLength()` method added a Null Character i.e. `\u0000`

Comment: Why do you call `setLnegth` and then appending?..

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but my output is "123_","12_","12 _"

Comment: Ok, mystery solved, I did not know that '\u0000' is a reserved character which indicates the end of string as pointed out by Paul John. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null character is a reserved character that indicates the end of the string, so if you print something followed by \u0000, nothing else after it will be printed.

Answer is here [Why stringbuilder stops adding elements after using the null character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449887/why-stringbuilder-stops-adding-elements-after-using-the-null-character)

Comment: This is not happening in my eclipse Java 8 environment..... I am reading the manual and am in disbelief. Something is amiss. I agree with you but the compiler is doing something different.

Answer (score 0):

When I execute your code, my output is the following

```
123_
12_
12_
```

Which seems more logical to me, as

```
System.out.println(sb + "_");
```

first computes sb.toString() and then ads "_" to the resulting String.

As an example, take the following lines:

```
String a = sb + "_"; // This line compiles
StringBuffer a = sb + "_"; // This line does not compile
```

The second line shows an error "cannot convert from String to StringBuffer", and as you can see the result of adding a String to a StringBuffer using the + operator is String.