# C server returns only first message

Tags: java, c, sockets

I have a simple C server and simple Java client. Client takes input from keyboard and sends it to server. Server prints it and sends it back. But it works only for the first time, what can be the problem?

Main:

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Client cli = new Client();
        cli.connect();

        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            cli.send(sc.nextLine());
            System.out.println(cli.rec());
        }

    }
}
```

Client:

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client {

    Socket socket;
    OutputStreamWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;

    public void connect() {

        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 50001);
            socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void send(String message) {
        try {
            this.out.write(message + "\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            this.out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String rec() {
        try {
            return in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MY_PORT     50001
#define MAXBUF      1024

int main(int Count, char *Strings[])
{   int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in self;
    char buffer[MAXBUF];
    int clientfd;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    int addrlen=sizeof(client_addr);
    int yes = 1;

    /*---Create streaming socket---*/
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 )
    {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(errno);
    }

    /*---Initialize address/port structure---*/
    bzero(&self, sizeof(self));
    self.sin_family = AF_INET;
    self.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT);
    self.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == 0)
        {
            printf("Socket options was set.\n"); //TODO
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Set socket options failure.\n"); //TODO
        }

    /*---Assign a port number to the socket---*/
    if ( bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&self, sizeof(self)) != 0 )
    {
        perror("socket--bind");
        exit(errno);
    }

    /*---Make it a "listening socket"---*/
    if ( listen(sockfd, 20) != 0 )
    {
        perror("socket--listen");
        exit(errno);
    }

    clientfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addrlen);

    /*---Forever... ---*/
    while (1)
    {
        memset(buffer, 0, MAXBUF);
        /*---accept a connection (creating a data pipe)---*/
        printf("%s:%d connected\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));

        recv(clientfd, buffer, MAXBUF, 0);
        printf("Server got: %s", buffer);
        //sprintf(buffer, "%s\r\n", buffer);
        /*---Echo back anything sent---*/
        printf("sending...\n");
        int n = send(clientfd, buffer, MAXBUF, 0);
        printf("sent: %d\n", n);
    }

    /*---Close data connection---*/
            close(clientfd);

    /*---Clean up (should never get here!)---*/
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't check how many bytes was returned by `recv`. You assume you can send `MAXBUF` of `buffer`. client code implies it is only reading one line.

Comment: I think that `accpet` call should go inside the while loop. I've been playing around with sockets recently, take a look at my [messy gist here](https://gist.github.com/Jacajack/82c5904d9cce10fdd574e5ff77a2214e#file-sock-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here goes the **root cause**. (Skip to fix if you don't want the details)

1. When you were sending data back to Java Client, you were sending the length of the data as MAXBUF (1024) in your case.
2. Now, What apparently happened is java received 1024 characters as the input. You can see this in your (C-language) Server output. `sent: 1024`
   To fill for this remaining characters, **it sends the ASCII value 0** (which is NUL) 
   You can verify this by removing your readLine() API in your java code and adding this.

   ```
       StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
       while ((value = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
           if(value != 0)
               strb.append((char) value);
           System.out.print(value + ":" + (char) value+",");
       }
       return strb.toString();
   ```
3. The first time request comes from server back to client with user-entered-data followed by remaining nulls, the following happens

   - Since readLine() API was used. It reads till `\n` or `\r` character. So you're able to see the output.
   - At this point bufferedReader still has those NUL characters stored in its buffer.
   - Now when second time we try to read from this reader, it first tries to empty the old buffer until (No `\n` or `\r` was found, except all NULs). It appends all these to the StringBuilder (which it internally uses) followed by which it appends the newly read string to the builder.
     **If This NUL character occurs, then all characters appended to the StringBuilder disappears in its buffer**. ([Explanation given here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17449887/1925997)) You can try this with this code:

     ```
     StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder().append((char)0).append("kishore");
     System.out.println(str.toString()); // Output : Blank
     ```
   - That's the reason you were not able to see the output. So you client and server communication had no issue.
4. **Fix:** Change your "C" Server code to send the proper length.

   ```
       int bytes = recv(clientfd, buffer, MAXBUF, 0);
       ...
       int n = send(clientfd, buffer, bytes, 0);
   ```

With this it should work.

Comment: @chris01 I tried this code with the given change. It worked. I tried the `accept` function in loop as well, but it didn't work. because the previous client was never disconnected. Writing accept in the loop resulted in `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out` in java side and CPP server logs is stuck at `accept` because no new client is connecting and nor is he responding to existing client.

Comment: So, this solution above is working. I am very glad, it drove me crazy. And Second. The accept is outside because I want that one client that connects to comunicate endlessly with server, so why should I have accept in the loop? It will be waste of connections.

Comment: Yes, `accept` should not be in the while loop. That was the point I was making for chris01's answer. Writing it inside means your client also needs to create so many connections which is not needed for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this will solve your problem, but I think that your `accept` function call should go in the `while` loop, as I saw that Jacajack just commented.

This way, the loop will accure each time you will recieve a connection. It should look like this:

**Example**:

```
/* Do what's in the loop every time that you accept a connection */

while (clientfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addrlen))
{
    memset(buffer, 0, MAXBUF);
    /*---accept a connection (creating a data pipe)---*/
    printf("%s:%d connected\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));

    int iResult = recv(clientfd, buffer, MAXBUF, 0); 
    // iResult is the amount of data from recv

    // Handle information and echo it back 


}
```

Additionally, I think you should implement some kind of protocol that will **validate the message that the server got** (see that it really does ends with a end of line or any other validitation that you would like to specify).

Comment: I don't think this will help. If you look at the java code, the client is not trying to connect second time in order to send second message. He just connected once and is sending multiple messages. Changing the accept to while loop will result in`java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out` in java side because no new client is connecting to CPP Server, so he is stuck at `accept` function and nor is he responding to existing client.

Answer (score 0):

The accept must be inside your endless-loop.
It accepts any new connection there. So you only accept the 1st one and no other.

listen is the last call you do only once. Then you do it per connection. Thats also the way if you would have some scalability (e.g. fork at accept).

Comment: I don't think this will help. If you look at the java code, the client is not trying to connect second time in order to send second message. He just connected once and is sending multiple messages. Changing the accept to while loop will result in`java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out` in java side because no new client is connecting to CPP Server, so he is stuck at `accept` function and nor is he responding to existing client.

Comment: I guess the problem is about accepting just one client and having the connection alive so you can respond on it multiple times. Its something like the keep-alive of HTTP.

Comment: @Bandi: I am talking about the C server, not the Java client.

Comment: @chris01: When I want to comunicate just with one client and the same client, the accept is outside. It is working that way for me.

Comment: If you have just one connection and no one more that is true. I am not talking about only one consecutive - I mean only one in the lifetime of the server. But normally a server should be able to accept more than 1 connection in his lifetime and then there the accept is inside a loop. Maybe it is a 2nd problem in the code but I read it is not working for a 2nd client.